# What should the TwoDimensionalShape Class contain?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I am trying to do an exercise with polymorphism in C++ to calculate the area and volume of the figures int the following hierarchy

```
                                       Shape
                 TwoDimensionalShape            ThreeDimensional

            Circle    Square   Triangle           Sphere   Cube
```

I declared a virtual function getArea and getVolume in the Shape class, and for example in the Circle class the function is:

```
double Circle::getArea() const
{
    return 3.14*radius*radius;
}
```

where radius is private in the circle class.

But I am stuck a little on what should I include in the TwoDimensionalShape class and if I should declare a variable area inside it.

Comment: What would the volume of a 2D shape be?

Comment: The Volume will be used for the Sphere and Cube Classes from the Class ThreeDimensional

Comment: @juanchopanza Zero, as the R^3-Lebesgue measure of a two dimensional sub-manifold is zero. (I hope he will not start with non-measurable sets here, they hardly qualify as shape IMO.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a data member inside intermediate level classes. They are just for hierarchy abstraction, in order to say *Circle is a TwoDimensionalShape*. You may later have some function taking reference to `TwoDimensionalShape` and where you can pass `Circle` or `Triangle`, but not any other non-TwoDimensionalShape.

As a data-member, you can have some flag within `Shape` itself. The data member would specify the type of current object. You can have `enum` for the same. This will be used for static-asserts and well as runtime checks. This may also help in some ways without need of virtual functions.